# Extracting Data from XML to List<>

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, linq-to-xml

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Record>
  <File name="1.mot">
    <Line address="040004" data="0720" />
    <Line address="040037" data="31" />
    <Line address="04004C" data="55AA55AA" />
  </File>
  <File name="2.mot">
    <Line address="00008242" data="06" />
    <Line address="00008025" data="AFC8" />
    <Line address="00009302" data="476F6C64" />
  </File>
</Record>
```

What I want to do is to extract the information from the XML and convert that to list. Although I kind of don't know where and how to start. I've googled samples, and questions and the code below is what I've managed to construct so far. I'm not even sure if this code is appropriate for what I wanted to happen. This list will be used for some kind of lookup in the program. Like in file `1.mot`, program would read 1.mot, read the xml file, parse both files, extract the info from the xml file and then do a search function to verify if the info in the xml exists in `1.mot`.

```
XElement xmlReqs = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
List<Requirement> reqs = new List<Requirement>();
foreach (var xmlReq in xmlReqs.Elements("File"))
{
    string name = xmlReqs.Attribute("name").Value);
    List<InfoLine> info = new List<InfoLine>();
    foreach (var xmlInfo in xmlReq.Elements("Line"))
    {
      string address = xmlProduct.Attribute("address").Value;
      string data = xmlProduct.Attribute("data").Value;
    }
reqs.Add(new Requirement(address, data));
}
```

A friend of mine suggested something about using int array or string array and then using this *`reqs.Find(val => val[0]==target)`* but I'm not sure how to do so. I'm not well-versed with linq, but what I've gathered, it seems to be quite notable and powerful (?).

Anyway, will the code above work? And how do I call the objects from the list to use for the lookup function of the program?

UPDATE:
Program would be reading 1.mot or 2.mot (depending on the user preference, that's why file name in xml needs to be specified) simultaneously (or not) with the xml file.
1.mot file contains:

```
S0030000FC
S21404000055AA55AA072000010008000938383138D7
S21404001046305730343130302020202027992401B0
...
```

Address starts at the 3rd byte. So yeah, would be comparing the data to these bunch of lines.

Comment: So `1.mot` and 'the xml` are two different things?  How are you reading `1.mot`?  What does 'comparing the data to these bunch of lines' involve?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that. StreamReader does the reading for `1.mot`. And from there, parses the file depending on the format of every record line within `1.mot`. It reads the first type (S_) to identify the format, also the size of the address. Well, for every record line, every byte in the data field corresponds to a specific address. So if I take the sample into consideration `S21404001046305730343130302020202027992401B0` the data field would be `46305730343130302020202027992401` and if the address is 04000D, corresponding address should be `27`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can de-serialize the xml file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Record));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Record record = (Record)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Record")]
    public class Record
    {
        [XmlElement("File")]
        public List<File> files {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("File")]
    public class File
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Line")]
        public List<Line> lines {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("Line")]
    public class Line
    {
        [XmlAttribute("address")]
        public string address {get;set;}
        [XmlAttribute("data")]
        public string data {get;set;}
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Code automatically reads XML file an creates class containing the data.  The tags in the XML file are parsed by the serialization library and the classes are automatically created ad filled with data.  The variable 'record' is the root which contains all the data.

Comment: How will I able to use the data within the classes? I can't figure out how to call record which contains all data necessary.

Comment: The variable 'record' is the root class. So you can use record.files[0].name or record.files[0].lines[0].data

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was able to figure it out. Although, after a few hours of trial and error. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `XmlSerializer` to handle the reading of the XML.  Create some classes that look like these:

```
public class Record
{
    [XmlElement("File")]
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Line")]
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; } 
}

public class Line
{
    [XmlAttribute("address")]
    public int Address { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise like so:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Record));

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("XMLFile1.xml"))            
{
    var record = (Record) serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    var first = record.Files.Single(f => f.Name == "1.mot");
    var second = record.Files.Single(f => f.Name == "2.mot");
}
```

Comment: With regards to 'verifying the info', I'm thinking of using string `address` to convert to int and use the value to compute for a range of addresses (start and end address). From there, maybe some sort of formula to compute how many chars to count from the start of the line to what supposed to be the address allocation with the data. `data` would simply be there to comapre and check if it matches.

Comment: OK, I've removed my interpretation as it sounds like I didn't really capture what you're after.  It's still not entirely clear to me what you're comparing to what - it sounds like some pre-existing data to the XML? The above reads your XML and shows how you could get the individual `File`s within it.  I think we need a lot more information on the next part!

Comment: Program would be reading 1.mot or 2.mot (depending on what file is chosen, input in the console) simultaneously (or not) with the xml file. I will edit my post, I'll try to provide additional information.