# Iterating through a list generated from xml

Tags: c#, xml, list

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Record>
  <File name="slc4t0_appl_release.mot">
    <Line address="040004" data="0720" />
    <Line address="040037" data="31" />
    <Line address="04004C" data="55AA55AA" />
  </File>
  <File name="SRLCAM4T0_PS_163_780A.PAR.mot">
    <Line address="00008242" data="06" />
    <Line address="00008025" data="AFC8" />
    <Line address="00009302" data="476F6C64" />
  </File>
</Record>
```

And previously, I asked for help how to accss and extract the information from said XML. Fortunately, some provided solutions how to deal with this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434257/extracting-data-from-xml-to-list). Also, I was able to call upon the objects by making use of the index (is that the right term?). Like so... `record.files[0].lines[0].data`

Now, I want to be able to iterate through the files and lines one-by-one. So program would go through `files[0]` first then loop through `lines[]` until all is done then would next go through `files[1]` once again looping `files[]` inside it and so on.

I thought it would be easy as

```
int i, ii;
for (i = 0; index <= meh._record.files.Count - 1; index++)
{
    for (ii = 0; ii <= meh._record.files[i].lines.Count - 1; ii++)
    {
        //code
        string addr, dat;
        addr = record.files[i].lines[ii].address;
        dat = record.files[i].lines[ii].data;
        //so on...
    }
}
```

When I tried it, it seems to be doing what I wanted. But I might still be doing something wrong here. Or if there's a better alternative for this, that would be great.

Comment: Code either does what you want or does not. You need to figure it out first so it is clear what kind of help you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need the index `i` and `ii` other than for accessing particular item in corresponding list, I think it will be cleaner and more readable if you use `foreach` for this task :

```
foreach(var file in meh._record.files)
{
    foreach(var line in file.lines)
    {
        //code
        string addr, dat;
        addr = line.address;
        dat = line.data;
        //so on...
    }
}
```

From what you've posted so far, your codes seems to be doing what you described already, but we can't be more sure then you do :)

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach to read your `xml` and access each element.

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(s);     
var q = from b in xml.Root.Descendants("File")
    select new
{
    File =  (string)b.Attribute("name").Value,

    Lines = b.Descendants("Line").Select(l=> new { Address= l.Attribute("address").Value, Data = l.Attribute("data").Value})            

};
```

And you can access the items as shown here.

```
foreach (var rec in q)
{
    Console.Write("File = {0}", rec.File);
    foreach(var line in rec.Lines)
    {
        Console.Write("Address = {0} , Data = {1}", line.Address, line.Data);
    }

}
```

Working code can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kSjVUS)